# Core-Plot: How to keep axises are always at bottom-left side of screen

Tags: core-plot

Currently, I can keep the axises at bottom-left side of screen by using **CPConstraints**, **isFloatingAxis** and set a properly value for **orthogonalCoordinateDecimal**, but when I change the xRange and yRange value, the axises are moved, so is there anyway to keep them always at bottom-left side without re-calculate and change **orthogonalCoordinateDecimal** value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an workaround solution that just set **FloatingAxis = YES** and  **rthogonalCoordinateDecimal is 0**, do not use CPConstraints, then the axises are always stay at the bottom-left border.

Comment: Hey, isFloatingAxis,CPConstraints is not showing intellisense in my project.Any file to be imported other than #import <UIKit/UIKit.h> and #import "CorePlot-CocoaTouch.h" ?(however orthogonalCoordinateDecimal works)